# Should an Instance of a Swift Class be assigned to `nil` to see the deinitializer in action?

Tags: swift, class, option-type, swift5, deinit

Swift can have Deinitializers (Like C++ Destructors) for Classes. When I am using a Non-Optional Instance of a Class (That is, `var obj: Class` not `var obj: Class?`), I am unable to see the message printed by the Deinitializer. However, when an Optional Instance of a Class is assigned to `nil`, the Deinitializer message pops up. Even when a Non-Optional Instance of a Class is used, it would be automatically deallocated when the Reference Count gets over, right ? Then, Why is the deinitializer message not popping up for Non-Optional Instances ?

**Example Code to reproduce this behavior:**

```swift
class A: CustomStringConvertible
{
    var value: Int
    var description: String
    {
        get
        {
            "A (value = \(value))"
        }
    }
    
    init(_ value: Int)
    {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    deinit
    {
        print("\(self) is being deinitialized !")
    }
}

var a: A = A(5)
print(a)
var aOpt: A? = A(10)
print(aOpt!)
aOpt = nil
```

**Output:**

```
A (value = 5)
A (value = 10)
A (value = 10) is being deinitialized !
```

Comment: Please test the code in a project, the memory management of Playgrounds is different.

Comment: Hi, I ran this code in a Console App Project. I didn't use Playgrounds.

Comment: A *Command Line Interface* behaves like a Playground. Properties on the top level are strong  references and are deallocated (silently) while the process is being terminated.

Comment: The Program terminates with exit code 0, meaning that there's no error. Then, it should print the deinitialzer message of the Non-Optional Instance too right ?

Comment: No, you don't get `deinit` messages in a standard (macOS) app either when the user presses ⌘Q.

Comment: Then if we want to see object deallocation, we have to use an optional and assign it to `nil`. There's no other way, right ?

Comment: A process deallocates **all** objects during termination. Just trust the framework.

Comment: You can simply use `let _ = A(20)` to see deinitializing message. Or declare variables like `a` and `aOpt` in a `do { }` block.

Comment: @Omid Golparvar I wasn't aware of these two methods. Thank You :-)

Comment: @vadian "A process deallocates all objects during termination." I think I know what you mean, but this is probably confusing to readers who aren't familiar with the OS details. During termination, `deinit` is not run, and neither is `free`. The entire memory pool of the process is simply reclaimed by the OS in a bulk action without considering any data organization (such as objects) created by the program.

Comment: (I see this is exactly what Christophe explains in the paragraph beginning "And with Swift, once the programme is terminated, it's over." As the answer notes, this is not like C++, which does promise that destructors will run, although the language cannot fully deliver on that promise. This behavior goes back to ObjC, and makes program termination much faster.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deinitialization is managed via the [**swift ARC**](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). To simplify: it is triggered for an object (not a variable) when there is no longer a valid reference to the object.  This happens for example when setting an optional variable to `nil`.  But also by assigning another object to a non-optional variable.  And also when variables are no longer in scope (e.g. exiting a function when the object is not returned).

The following adaptation of your code shows these different cases (see the comments for the details):

```
class A
{
    var value: Int
    init(_ value: Int)
    {
        self.value = value
        print("A object with ivalue \(value) was initialized")
    }
    deinit
    {
        print("A object with value \(value) was deinitialized")
    }
}

func test() {
    var a: A = A(5)       // (5) is initialized
    let b = A(6)          // (6) is initialized
    a = b                 // no reference anymore to (5) so it is deinitialized
    //a = nil             // not allowed because it's not optional
     
    var aOpt: A? = A(10)  // (10) in intialized
    aOpt = nil            // no reference anymore to (10) so it is deinitialized
}                         // a dies, so no reference anymore to (6) which is deinitialized
test()
print ("This is the end")
```

I managed to get all the objects to be deinitialized before reaching the final print, simply by declaring them in a function body.  This gives a tighter control on the variable lifecycles. But when you declare global or static variables, it's different, because the variables continue to exist until termination of a programme. Would my snippet run the `test()` outside of the function, the object (6) would not be deinitialized, since it would still be still referenced by a variable.

And with Swift, once the programme is terminated, it's over. Unlike C++, there is no guarantee that the remaining objects are properly deinitialized: Swift gives back the the resources to the the system without individually deinitializing every object.

If this is a problem for you, the best is to avoid global variables as much as possible (this is in any case a good practice). And if you have to use them,  make sure the the app has a single exit point that cleans the object properly.

Comment: `Unlike C++, there is no guarantee that the remaining objects are properly deinitialized` - are you sure about the C++ part? Terminating any kind of program, regardless the language used to build it,  can lead to resource leaking, especially if that termination is caused by some unexpected conditions, like signals.

Comment: @Cristik in C++ there is a difference between normal and abnormal termination. The normal ending of a C++ program (returning from main or reaching last statement of main) causes the objects to be destroyed, include any object with static lifetime (e.g. global variables). It’s a guarantee on the object lifecycle. Of course, in C++ you might have to abort and abnormally terminate:   clean up in then brutal without destruction. There is an exit shortcut, which is not recommended: it does  a normal termination, except for local variables:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit

Comment: This is not entirely true, heap-allocated global variables don't get "destroyed", meaning the destructor for them is not called, even in regular program termination. Which is similar to how Swift works, with the exception here that you cannot allocate a class on another memory space then the heap. So, if we're comparing apples to apples, C++ and Swift has the same behaviour when it comes to heap allocated data.

Comment: @Cristik You have a point here: if objects are created in the free store, it’s indeed up to you to delete them to get the destructor called.  But the equivalent in C++ to ARC are smart pointers, and the objects pointed to are automatically deleted when there’s no smart pointer pointing to it left.  And smart pointers are destroyed according to the normal rules, which leads to proper clean-up and systematic destruction at the end.  Same if normal pointers are encapsulated in objects, which should then abide by the rule of 3 (or 5) to ensure proper destruction of free-store objects.

Comment: But let’s not open a C++ discussion here. I mentioned it only because OP was referring to it. My main intent was to clarify that Swift is not C++ and initialization/deinitialization is not exactly the same thing than construction/destruction.

Comment: Good point about the smart pointers, as they are the norm these days, and agreed that they are the counterpart to ARC's reference counting mechanism. Maybe embed this in the answer, so other non-daily C++ developers don't misinterpret that part :)